# Is there any threshold-crypto library that is production-ready?

Tags: threshold-cryptography

I am wondering if there is any available threshold crypto library that is well-audited and ready to be used in production.
Any pointer is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

The [ZenGo k-of-n multi-party ECDSA library](https://github.com/ZenGo-X/multi-party-ecdsa), written in Rust, has been audited by Kudelski security in late 2019. See the audit report [here](https://github.com/ZenGo-X/multi-party-ecdsa/blob/master/audits/REPORT_final_2019-10-22.pdf).

Comment: We have created a WebAssembly port of the project so you can use it everywhere (e.g. The browser): https://github.com/CoinFabrik/wasm-multi-party-ecdsa